# Excel VBA executing SQL Server stored procedure - result set throwing error 3704

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a SQL Server stored procedure from Excel VBA. The procedure returns rows into a result set object. However, while running the code, it throws an error:

> 3704 Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Note:
There is no problem with the database connection because `Select` query running on the same connection object are working fine.

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
ThisWorkbook.initialize
cn.Provider = "sqloledb"
cn.Properties("Data Source").Value = ThisWorkbook.server
cn.Properties("Initial Catalog").Value = ThisWorkbook.db
cn.Properties("User ID").Value = "xxxxx"
cn.Properties("Password").Value = "xxxxx"
cn.Open

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.CommandText = "Generate_KPI_Process_Quality_Check_RunTime"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.ActiveConnection = cn

Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@currentMonth", adChar, adParamInput, 255, cmb_month.Value)
cmd.Parameters.Append prm

Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@center", adChar, adParamInput, 255, cmb_center.Value)
cmd.Parameters.Append prm

rst.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rst.CursorLocation = adUseServer
rst.LockType = adLockOptimistic

rst.Open cmd

If (rst.BOF And rst.EOF) Then
'Some Code
End If
```

Comment: At what line does it throw this error?

Comment: Hi @jerussell, It throws an error at the If **(rst.BOF And rst.EOF) Then...** statement at the end of the Code segment.

Comment: @Abhishek Panda Did any of these answers fix your problem? If so, upvote and/or mark as answered.

Comment: I am positive that you need to use the set keyword though or delete the first statement and use the solution proposed by @mehow

Answer (score 3):

Put

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

in the stored procedure -- this will prevent output text generation like "1 record(s) updated".

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! this answer is a little terse, can you give a little explanation to how this solves the problem?

Comment: Corley, looks like stored procedure output interfering with result recordset so OLEDB provider can't receive the recordset. SET NOCOUNT ON prevents output text generation on INSERTs/UPDATEs and so on.

Comment: [Another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950443/run-time-error-3704-operation-is-not-allowed-when-the-object-is-closed-in-vb6) asks about this same error (in VB6) and SET NOCOUNT was the suggested answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide more parameters for the `Open` method of [**`Recordset Object`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

try `rst.Open cmd, cn`

Comment: The connection object is an optional argument. It might fix the problem caused by the incorrect assignment "cmd.ActiveConnection = cn" though

Comment: Indeed, it would work. However, if he decides to adopt your solution, he would better cleanup his code by deleting the offending statement that would potentially become a source of confusion in the future.

Comment: @mehow - I tried your solution and I get this:

Run-time error '3707':

Cannot change the ActiveConnection property of a Recordset object which has a Command object at its source

Comment: @AbhishekPanda have you tried [**command.execute**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681559(v=vs.85).aspx) method?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Set keyword to assign the object:

```
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
```

otherwise, the default property of the Connection object (which happen to be the connection string) will be assigned in lieu of the Connection object itself.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, that didn't work. It's still the same old 3704 error.

Comment: I am positive that this is a problem and that you have to use set or delete the whole statement and use @mehow solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just put another recordset that will contain resultsets

```
Dim rst1 As New ADODB.Recordset
SET rst1=rst.NextRecordset 'this will return the first resultset

If rst1.BOF or rst1.EOF Then...
    'some code
End If
```